# Find $\| \vec{b} \|$ for the coordinate vector $[\vec{b}]_{B}=[2,1,4,-3]$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem from *Linear Algebra* (Fraleigh):

*Let $(\vec{a}_{1},\vec{a}_{2},\vec{a}_{3},\vec{a}_{4})$ be an ordered orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R^{4}}$, and let $[2,1,4-3]$ be the coordinate vector of a vector $\vec{b}$ in $\mathbb{R^{4}}$ relative to this basis.*

This is my solution:

$B=(\vec{a}_{1},\vec{a}_{2},\vec{a}_{3},\vec{a}_{4})$

$[\vec{b}]_{B}=[2,1,4,-3]$

So,

$\vec{b}=2\vec{a}_{1}+1\vec{a}_{2}+4\vec{a}_{3}-3\vec{a}_{4}=\vec{a}_{5}$

The final step is compute...

$\| \vec{b} \|=\sqrt{\vec{a}_{5_{1}}^{2}+\vec{a}_{5_{2}}^{2}+\vec{a}_{5_{3}}^{2}+\vec{a}_{5_{4}}^{2}}$

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it´s essential that $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ is orthonormal:

$||b||^2=(b,b)=(2a_1+1a_2+4a_3-3a_4,2a_1+1a_2+4a_3-3a_4)=2^2\underbrace{(a_1,a_1)}_{=1}+2.1\underbrace{(a_1,a_2)}_{=0}+...1^2\underbrace{(a_2,a_2)}_{=1}+...+(-3)^2\underbrace{(a_4,a_4)}_{=1}=2^2+1^2+4^2+3^2=30$

and so $||b||=\sqrt{30}=$

You have $a_{5_1}=b_1=(b,a_1)=(2a_1,a_1)=2$ and so on